# Deserializing mongodb "$numberLong" in spray-json

Tags: mongodb, scala, spray-json

I've got following problem -> I have case class which has among other things - timestamp as Long.  This serialized timestamp in Json from mongodb looks like this:

```
"timestamp" : { "$numberLong" : "1460451019201" }
```

Can you tell me how to properly deserialize it into my case class using spray-json?

Comment: Please add the target case class. Do you want to keep it as a `Long`? `$numberLong` is a 64-bit integer, so that would map directly.

Comment: For example User(name: String, timestamp: Long)